# Function for simulation game in R

Tags: r, simulation

I have a classic dice simulation problem, which I'm struggling to implement since I'm new with R syntax. The function (which I have called simu) works as follows:

1. Start with 0 points
2. Simulate n random draws of three six-sided dice
3. For each draw:

   - If sum of three dice >12 --> +1 point
   - If sum of three dice <6  --> -1 point
   - Otherwise (ie sum between 6 and 12):

     - If three dice have same number --> +5 points
     - Otherwise  --> 0 points
4. Return total # of points obtained at the end of n simulations

Having tried a number of different methods I seem to be pretty close with:

```
simu <- function(n){
  k <- 0
  for(i in 1:n) {
    a <- sample(y,1,replace=TRUE)
    b <- sample(y,1,replace=TRUE)
    c <- sample(y,1,replace=TRUE)  
    if ((a + b + c) > 12)  {
      k <- k+1
    } else if ((a + b + c) < 6)  {
      k <- k-1
    } else if ((a == b) & (b == c))  {
      k <- k+5
    } else k <- 0
  }
  return(k)
}
```

The problem seems to be that I am failing to iterate over new simulations (for a, b, c) for each "i" in the function.

Comment: It doesn't look there's anything wrong with the function, you are just resetting `k` to zero most of the time, so if you call `simu(n)` with `n > 1` the odds are you will get `k <- 0`. Isn't it that `Otherwise 0 points` means `Otherwise add zero points`?

Comment: You are correct - the last else statement should have been k <- k + 0. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have commented the only issue I have found... The last `else` that always re-initialize `k` to 0. Instead it should have been `k <- k + 0` but it does not change anything to remove it.

```
y <- seq(1,6) # 6-sided dice

simu <- function(n){
  k <- 0
  for(i in 1:n) {
    a <- sample(y,1,replace=TRUE)
    b <- sample(y,1,replace=TRUE)
    c <- sample(y,1,replace=TRUE)  
    if ((a + b + c) > 12)  {
      k <- k+1
    } else if ((a + b + c) < 6)  {
      k <- k-1
    } else if ((a == b) & (b == c))  {
      k <- k+5
    } #else k <- 0
  }
  return(k)
}
```

The results look quite fine :

```
> simu(1000)
[1] 297
> simu(100)
[1] 38
```

Comment: Also, maybe `sample(6, 1)` will do, in this case it's exactly the same and much simpler and readable. As a bonus, there would be no need for an extra variable `y`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use R, then you should learn to create vectorized operations instead of 'for' loops.  Here is a simulation of 1 million rolls of the dice that took less than 1 second to calculate.  I am not sure how long the 'for' loop approach would have taken.

```
n <- 1000000  # trials
start <- proc.time()  # time how long it takes
result <- matrix(0L, ncol = 6, nrow = n)
colnames(result) <- c('d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'sum', 'same', 'total')

# initial the roll of three dice
result[, 1:3] <- sample(6L, n * 3L, replace = TRUE)

# compute row sum
result[, 'sum'] <- as.integer(rowSums(result[, 1:3]))

# check for being the same
result[, 'same'] <- result[,1L] == result[, 2L] & result[, 2L] == result[, 3L]

result[, 'total'] <- ifelse(result[, 'sum'] > 12L,
                      1L,
                      ifelse(result[, 'sum'] < 6L,
                             -1L,
                             ifelse(result[, 'same'] == 1L,
                                    5L,
                                    0L
                             )
                      )
)

table(result[, 'total'])

    -1      0      1      5 
 46384 680762 259083  13771 

cat("simulation took:", proc.time() - start, '\n')
simulation took: 0.7 0.1 0.8 NA NA
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that's what you need, but you can try something like that:

```
# Draw the dice(s) - returns vector of length == n_dices
draw <- function(sides = 6, dices = 3){
  sample(1:sides, dices, replace = T)
}
# test simulation x and return -1, 0, 1, 1 or 5
test <- function(x){
  (sum(x) > 12)*1 + (sum(x) < 6)*(-1) + (sum(x) >= 6 & 
                                           sum(x) <= 12 & 
                                           var(x) == 0)*5 
}
# simulate n draws of x dices with y sides
simu <- function(sides = 6, dices = 3, n = 100){
  sum(replicate(n, test(draw(sides, dices))))
}
# run simulations of 100 draws for 1, 2, ..., 11, 12-side dices (3 dices each simulation) 
dt <- lapply(1:12, function(side) replicate(100, simu(side, 3, 100)))
# plot dicstribution of scores
par(mfrow = c(3,4))
lapply(1:length(dt), function(i) hist(dt[[i]],
                                      main = sprintf("%i sides dice", i),
                                      xlab = "Score"
                                      )
       )
```

[image]